# Cascading two or more LSTM models

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm, prediction, forecasting

I am working on a case study where i want to make a comparison of performance between a standard LSTM model and a cascaded lstm models as provided in the picture (you could see the block diagram). I would like to know what function could be useful to stack these models. it worth mentioning that each output sequence is an input to the next block, i.e. the LSTM-1hr model has been cascaded with each other and the output block was separately trained in a supervised manner while freezing weights for the input block. The secondary block is initialized with the weights from the basic 1hr model.
[the image shows the block diagram of the models that i want to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUVSw.png)

Comment: What do you mean by a "useful function"? As you mentioned, stacking is about using outputs of one model as input of the next ones, so you merely need to connect layers together. You can check that: https://machinelearningmastery.com/stacking-ensemble-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.